# Order Dataframe Index based on a second Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

I got two DataFrames in Python, but the Column there are to be used as Indexes (CodeNumber) are not in the same order. There would be needed to order them equally; Follows the code:

```
#generating DataFrames:
d3 = {'CodeNumber': [1234, 1235, 111, 101], 'Date': [20150808, 20141201, 20180119, 20120720], 'Weight': [26, 32, 41, 24]}
d4 = {'CodeNumber': [1235, 1234, 101, 111], 'Date': [20160808, 20151201, 20180219, 20130720], 'Weight': [28, 25, 47, 3]}

data_SKU3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
data_SKU4 = pd.DataFrame(data=d4)
```

Then i set as an index the CodeNumber:

```
dados_SKU3.set_index('CodeNumber', inplace = True)
dados_SKU4.set_index('CodeNumber', inplace = True)
```

if we print the resulting DataFrames, note that data_SKU3 has the following order of Code Number: 1234 1235 111 101 , while data_SKU4: 1235 1234 101 111

Is there a way to order the Code Numbers so both DataFrames would be in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort values by `CodeNumber` on each dataframe by calling `.sort_values(by = 'CodeNumber')` before setting them as `index`:

```
d3 = {'CodeNumber': [1234, 1235, 111, 101], 'Date': [20150808, 20141201, 20180119, 20120720], 'Weight': [26, 32, 41, 24]}
d4 = {'CodeNumber': [1235, 1234, 101, 111], 'Date': [20160808, 20151201, 20180219, 20130720], 'Weight': [28, 25, 47, 3]}

data_SKU3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3).sort_values(by = 'CodeNumber')
data_SKU4 = pd.DataFrame(data=d4).sort_values(by = 'CodeNumber')

data_SKU3.set_index('CodeNumber', inplace = True)
data_SKU4.set_index('CodeNumber', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) if same number of values in both `indices`:

```
data_SKU3 = data_SKU3.set_index('CodeNumber').sort_index()
data_SKU4 = data_SKU4.set_index('CodeNumber').sort_index()

print (data_SKU3)
                Date  Weight
CodeNumber                  
101         20120720      24
111         20180119      41
1234        20150808      26
1235        20141201      32

print (data_SKU4)
                Date  Weight
CodeNumber                  
101         20180219      47
111         20130720       3
1234        20151201      25
1235        20160808      28
```

Another approach is use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by another `index` values, but is necessary unique values and only diiference is different ordering:

```
data_SKU3 = data_SKU3.set_index('CodeNumber')
data_SKU4 = data_SKU4.set_index('CodeNumber').reindex(index=data_SKU3.index)
print (data_SKU3)
                Date  Weight
CodeNumber                  
1234        20150808      26
1235        20141201      32
111         20180119      41
101         20120720      24

print (data_SKU4)
                Date  Weight
CodeNumber                  
1234        20151201      25
1235        20160808      28
111         20130720       3
101         20180219      47
```